# httpWebRequests send Post data and get the status code

Tags: c#, httprequest

I'm trying to convert some python code to C#.

The python code is using the requests module.

```
    post = {'customer_fid': self.customer_fid, 'salt': self.salt, 'token': token, 'customer_facebooktoken': self.customer_facebooktoken}

    request = self.session.post(self.baseurl + self.loginurl, data=post)
```

I've search several posts on google, but i can't find probably response.

I need a way to ask the server for the 4 parameters and get the statuscode afterwards.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for the `WebRequest` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx has a much better interface than System.Net.WebRequest.

Comment: Ah sweet, yea httpclient is just what i need. How do i send a post message just like the line i posted above.